# Print words which occurs more than once from a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find and print the words in a string that occurs more than one. And it works almost. I am however fighting with a small problem. The words a printed out twice since they occur twice in the sentence. I want them printed only once:

This is my code:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sentence = "is this a sentence or is this not ";
    String[] myStringArray = sentence.split(" "); //Split the sentence by space.

    int[] count = new int[myStringArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < myStringArray.length; j++){
           if (myStringArray[i].matches(myStringArray[j]))
               count[i]++;
           //else break;
       }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
            if (count[i] > 1)
          System.out.println("1b. - Tokens that occurs more than once: " + myStringArray[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A better idea might be to store the words in a hash. This way you only need to go through the sentence once, and just build up word list with counts, much more efficient.

Comment: Read about [Maps](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java. Your approach is far from optimal, despite being broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i+=2)` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work. If the sentence was:

"This time this is okay."

The word "this" is still checked twice.

Answer (score 0):

break on the first match, after incrementing. then it won't also increment the second match.

Comment: What if there were more than 1 word that repeated twice?

(e.g "I like to think that I like ice cream.")

Comment: break only breaks out of the innermost loop. the outer loop still runs.

Comment: What if you had the same word appear 3 times? Wouldn't you want the `count` for that word to be 3? Also, since the loop goes through values [0,0] -> [n-1, n-1] for [i,j] wouldn't a match for a word sometimes be itself? You wouldn't want to break right after it sees itself right?

Comment: it would, wouldn't it? the outer loop still runs, so it would increment the *first* match for *each* occurrence. but in any case, the OP only wanted to know which words occurred "more than once".

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems with it.

If you notice, your code will look through the list of n elements n^2 times.
If the occurrence of the word is twice. You will increment each word's count value twice.
What you need to keep track of is the set of words you have already seen, and check if a new word you encounter has already been seen or not.

If you had 3 occurrence of one word in your sentence, you each word would have a count of 3. The 3 is redundant data that doesn't need to be stored for each token, but rather just the word.

All this can be done easily if you know how a `Map` works.

Here is an implementation that would work.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "is this a sentence or is this not ";
        String[] myStringArray = sentence.split("\\s"); //Split the sentence by space.

        Map <String, Integer> wordOccurrences = new HashMap <String, Integer> (myStringArray.length);

        for (String word : myStringArray)
            if (wordOccurrences.contains(word))
                wordOccurrences.put(word, wordOccurrences.get(word) + 1);
            else wordOccurrences.put(word, 1);

        for (String word : wordOccurrences.keySet())
            if (wordOccurrences.get(word) > 1)
                System.out.println("1b. - Tokens that occurs more than once: " + word + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to find the repeating words from an input string. So, I suggest the following approach which is fairly simple:

> 1. Make a Hash Map instance. The key (String) will be the word and the value(Integer) will be the frequency of its occurrence.
> 2. Split the string using split("\s") method to make an array of only words.
> 3. Introduce an Integer type 'frequency' variable with initial value '0'.
> 4. Iterate of the string array and after checking frequency, add each element ( or word) to the map (if frequency for that key is 0) or if
>      the key (word) exists, only increment the frequency by 1.
> 5. So you are now left with each word and its frequency.

For example, if input string is "We are getting dirty as this earth is getting polluted. We must stop it."
So, the map will be
{ ("We",2), ("are",1), ("getting",2), ("dirty",1), ("as",1), ("this",1), ("earth",1), ("is",1), ("polluted.",1), ("must",1), ("stop",1), ("it.",1) }
Now you know what is next step and how to use it. I agree with Kaushik.