# Trouble with finding a substring in a string

Tags: java, string

I need to print all words which appear more once in a string.

example

```
input:s = "Java Ruby PHP.  Java is good. PHP please looks at Java"
```

output:

```
Java
PHP
```

Comment: Begin by splitting the string into tokens. Then, apply an algorithm that finds all tokens appearing more than once (this can be done in O(n)). Then print your result.

Comment: Here's the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. And here's the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately your answer could be doing quickly doing a Google search with the right keywords, try googling "Java String Repetitive Word Count"

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861334/print-words-which-occurs-more-than-once-from-a-string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    String str = "Java Ruby PHP.  Java is good. PHP please looks at Java";
    Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)(?=\\b.*\\1)").matcher(str);
    while(mat.find()){
        words.add(mat.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(words);
```

Also you can just split string by words and calculate count using Map. And then filter words with count > 1.